# Execute functions based on certain time delay and ignore other functions execution

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'm fiddling around setTimeOut javascript function. I've 5 function calls with different time delay. What I want is to execute only those functions which have a 500ms delay difference between each functions. I've created a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/vt7sanav/). Can someone suggest what should i do to check the delay between two functions is 500ms then execute the function else ignore the function.

Example: Packet1 comes in, should be sent(printed) straight away, Wait 500ms and within 500ms, ignore new msgs(function calls). Print only messages which have a delay of 500ms in between.

```
function postMessage(msg) {
  $("#msgBox").append("\n" + msg + " time:" + new Date().getSeconds() + ":" + new Date().getMilliseconds());
}

function makeRequest(msg) {
  postMessage(msg);
}

function makeRequestThrottled(msg) {
  // Packet1 comes in, should be sent straight away. wait 500ms and within 500ms,      ignore new msgs.
  postMessage(msg);
}

function sendMessage(msg, delay) {
  setTimeout(() =>
    makeRequestThrottled(msg), delay);
}

sendMessage("Packet1", 200);  //This should be printed straight away
sendMessage("Packet2", 600);   //Shouldn't be printed, difference is 400ms (Packet2 -Packet1)
sendMessage("Packet3", 1800);  // Should be printed, difference > 500ms (Packet3 -Packet2)
sendMessage("Packet4", 2400);  //Should be printed, difference > 500ms (Packet4 -Packet3)
sendMessage("Packet5", 2600);  //Shouldn't be printed, difference < 500ms (Packet4 -Packet5)
```

Comment: JavaScript is asychronous by nature. You're looking for a `promise`.

Comment: I think we can do it using setTimeout inside makeRequestThrottled call but not sure how

Answer (score 1):

The first way that came to mind to do what I *think* you're trying to do was to add a variable, `ignoring`, that the `makeRequestThrottled()` function will use to determine whether messages are currently being ignored. If not, post the message, set `ignoring = true`, and set a timeout that sets `ignoring` back to `false` after 500ms:

```js
function postMessage(msg) {
  $("#msgBox").append("<li>" + msg + " time:" + new Date().getSeconds() + ":" + new Date().getMilliseconds());
}

function makeRequest(msg) {
  postMessage(msg);
}

var ignoring = false;

function makeRequestThrottled(msg) {
  // Packet1 comes in, should be sent straight away. wait 500ms and within 500ms,      ignore new msgs.
  if (!ignoring) {
    postMessage(msg);
    ignoring = true;
    setTimeout(() => { ignoring = false }, 500);
  }
}

function sendMessage(msg, delay) {
  setTimeout(() =>
    makeRequestThrottled(msg), delay);
}

sendMessage("Packet1", 200);  //This should be printed straight away
sendMessage("Packet2", 600);   //Shouldn't be printed, difference is 400ms (Packet2 -Packet1)
sendMessage("Packet3", 1800);  // Should be printed, difference > 500ms (Packet3 -Packet2)
sendMessage("Packet4", 2400);  //Should be printed, difference > 500ms (Packet4 -Packet3)
sendMessage("Packet5", 2600);  //Shouldn't be printed, difference < 500ms (Packet4 -Packet5)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="msgBox"></ul>
```